# AWS DynamoDB query fails when attribute have certain characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto, boto3

If I run this query:

```
data = table.query(KeyConditionExpression = Key('id').eq('fasfas'),
                   FilterExpression=Attr(u'Absolute humidity[g/kg].3').eq(1))
```

I get the error:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Invalid FilterExpression: Syntax error; token: "humidity", near: "Absolute humidity ["
```

However If I run the query using their website it works. How can I make it work using boto3?

P.S. it also doens't work with underscores.

Answer (score 2):

> An expression attribute name is a placeholder that you use in an expression, as an alternative to an actual attribute name.
>
> [...]
>
> If an attribute name begins with a number or contains a space, a special character, or a reserved word, then you must use an expression attribute name to replace that attribute's name in the expression.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html

See also http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.query

Answer (score 0):

One of your parameter is not matching the datatype or a required parameter is missing such as range and hash key.

If you are looking for any records to match to your query then you need to scan instead of query.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html

> ValidationException Message: Varies, depending upon the specific
>   error(s) encountered
>
> This error can occur for several reasons, such as a required parameter
>   that is missing, a value that is out range, or mismatched data types.
>   The error message contains details about the specific part of the
>   request that caused the error.
>
> OK to retry? No

Hope it helps.

Comment: It sort of feels like you're guessing, here... `Syntax error; token: "humidity", near: "Absolute humidity ["` seems to rule out what you are suggesting might be the problem.